# Calculating exact duration time from a DateTime column in Postgres using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, pry, rails-console

I am trying to get a more accurate output than "about 2 hours" for duration time.

Currently, we are using `time_ago_in_words`

This looks like the below function in .erb

```
Duration: <%= time_ago_in_words(@sitrep.incident.created_at) %>

# I found the gem `dotiw` which lets me use:
distance_of_time_in_words(@sitrep.incident.created_at)
# However, there is an error and I can't get either to work in irb
```

This is my console output when attempting both. All help is appreciated

```
[1] pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers
=> Object
[2] pry(main)> t = Sitrep.last.incident.created_at

# redacted output    

=> Wed, 28 Nov 2018 21:47:45 UTC +00:00
[3] pry(main)> t
=> Wed, 28 Nov 2018 21:47:45 UTC +00:00
[4] pry(main)> time_ago_in_words(t)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.weeks\">Weeks</span>, <span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.days\">Days</span>, <span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.hours\">Hours</span>, and <span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.minutes\">Minutes</span>"
[5] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words(t)
NoMethodError: undefined method `seconds' for Wed, 28 Nov 2018 21:47:45 UTC +00:00:Time
Did you mean?  send
Did you mean?  send
from /Users/mmowris/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:371:in `method_missing'
[6] pry(main)>
```

The first method, time_ago_in_words works for our rails app. This .erb file sends an email, and the output would look something like:

```
Duration: about 2 hours
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? Why does this work in our rails project, but not irb? Why can't I get dotiw to work with the same input? Why can't i get taiw to work with the same input that works in production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the helper instead of including the helpers manually

```
 > helper.time_ago_in_words(2.hours.ago, true)
 => "2 hours" 

 > helper.time_ago_in_words((2.hours.ago + 5.seconds), true)
 => "1 hour, 59 minutes, and 55 seconds"
```